# WS2812B addressable led does not turn on after a certain point

Tags: pi-3, led, ws2812

I control thousands of leds using WS2812B led with Raspberry Pi 3. But since I have two different led types (both ws2212b), I use two different pins. Logically, I connected a 5V 10A power supply to the + and - poles of two different leds. I also connected the - end to the Raspberry Pi. Then I connected the green end of the addressable led to the D18 and D21 pins. I also use python and NeoPixel library to control leds. my problem; All the leds I connect to D21 are on. but the ones I connected to the D18 pin stop after the 361st led. No matter what I do, I can't burn it. When I change the ends of the pins, the led connected to D18 does not light up after the 361st led in the same way. but the led connected to D21 can be fully lit. I also tried the D12 pin. I get the same results as in D18.

What is the reason for this and how can I get around this situation?

Comment: swap the LED strips between D18 and D21

Comment: What happens if you **only** connect the ledstrip at D18? It might help to see a connection diagram.